# Update fitRows in Isotope on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I tried so much but I can't solve it. 
I am working on a grid layout with Isotope. After clicking the items the grid should update to the fitRows layout. 
It works perfectly with the exception of field number 2 and 3.

Here is the JSFiddle:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/brigi/kqh2m9y4/1/>
```

Can anyone help me out with this ? I am really grateful for any advice.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to happen? It looks like it is functioning in your fiddle.